# Where does the expression "long odds" come from?

Tags: etymology, expressions

In English we say an event has "long odds" if it is unlikely to happen, and "short odds" for the opposite.

The question is why?

Best I have been able to get from people:

- Long over even (if you are betting then the odds you get from the house are larger then for an even bet)
- Long as in something being a long way away and harder to hit/achieve/get to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bet on a *long shot*, you get *long odds*. It's possible that this is where *long odds* came from. The OED first citations are: *long odds* from 1764<sup>1</sup>; *long shot* with the meaning *unlikely* from 1796, but it's possible that the expression *long shot* was around earlier, but not written down.

And where did *long shot* come from? If you're shooting at something that's really far away, you are unlikely to hit it, so it's a *"long shot"*. First OED citation for *long shot* meaning a distant target: 1767,  but again it's possible that the expression was around earlier, but not written down.

And *short odds* are the opposite of *long odds*.

The phrase may have originally been nautical, which I suspect means it could have been around a long time before it appeared in print. From [1784](https://books.google.com/books?id=gLBFAQAAMAAJ&q=%22long+shot%22&dq=%22long+shot%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX7O2FzKDNAhUj6oMKHcsBA1g4ChDoAQggMAE):

> He chose, in the seaman's phrase, a long-shot distance. The engagement began, and continued to the last, at too great a distance. 'Never,' said Sir Samuel,' was there ever more powder and shot thrown away in one day.'

<sup>1</sup> ADDED IN EDIT: The OED has the following citation from 1764, but it's not clear to me that *long odds* has the usual meaning here:

> Presently news was brought that the favourite horse, on whose head Mr. Huntly had laid the long odds,..had fallen and broke his leg, within three yards of the goal.

You don't generally put "*long odds*" on a favorite horse. The next OED citation is from 1818. The earliest *"long odds"* I can find in Google books is from 1783, which appears to have the modern meaning, and there are a number of appearances of *"long odds"* clearly having the modern meaning, starting around 1793.

Comment: but Peter, where did "odds" come from??  maybe I misunderstand. .. Your first sentence just assumes *odds* exists with an established meaning at "that time".  WTH does "odds" mean?  When you think about ... it it's a weird term for "betting results payout" and/or "fractional chance".

Comment: The meaning of [*odds*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=odds) in gambling dates from the 16th century. So it did have a well-established meaning by the 18th century.

Comment: The term "long shot" is unlikely to be the origin of the term "long odds", because it doesn't account for the existence of the term "short odds".

Comment: @Dr. Funk: The OED mentions "long odds", but not "short odds". The first use of "long odds" I find in Google Books is 1783. The first use of "short odds" I find in Google Books is 1845. My hypothesis is that "long odds" came into existence first, and "short odds" was formed as a natural opposite to "long odds".

Comment: Hi Dr Funk.  I don't really know if that makes sense.  "Long" (from shooting sports) perfectly also suggests "short" (from shooting sports).  The idea that "long" and "short" come from shooting sports, seems extremely sensible and clear.

Comment: I found a number of instances of the term "long price" and "short price" being used relative to horses, horse betting, and horse sales in some century-old horse racing literature.  It seems unlikely that "long price" and "short price" derived from "long shot".

Comment: Here is an example of "long odds" being used in the context of betting.  Google books claims it is from 1764.

"Zoroaster took long odds that the match was off — offering a bean to half-a-quid — in other words, a guinea to a half-guinea — that Sybil would be the bride. His offer was taken at once by Jerry Juniper, and backed by the knight of Malta."

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22long+odds%22&safe=off&biw=1920&bih=979&source=lnt&tbs=sbd%3A1%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1600%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1780&tbm=bks

Comment: But wikipedia claims the collection, titled "The Lucubrations of Isaac Bickerstaff, Esq.", was originally published in 1711.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatler_(1709_journal)

Comment: @Dr. Funk: Google books seems to have messed up. That quote seems to really come from [Rookwood](https://books.google.com/books?id=RRoGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA245&lpg=PA245&dq=%22Zoroaster+took+long+odds+that+the+match+was+off%22&source=bl&ots=yWb3UmSRXv&sig=7Zj8DRHpZh2YUE_LgoBFR41IrxM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZqcn5m6vNAhVL5yYKHdJyBaAQ6AEIJDAC#v=onepage&q=%22Zoroaster%20took%20long%20odds%20that%20the%20match%20was%20off%22&f=false). William Harrison Ainsworth, the author of your Rookwood book, was [born](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Harrison_Ainsworth) in 1805.

Comment: Must be a database error then.

Comment: Here's a digitized copy of "The Lucubrations of Isaac Bickerstaff, Esq.": https://archive.org/details/lucubrationsisa06addigoog

Comment: Unfortunately, the OCR that has been done on it is pretty awful, so searching it is basically useless.  But the typeface doesn't seem to match the snippet from google books.

Comment: The other bizarre thing is that the book by William Harrison Ainsworth is not titled "Rockwood"; it is titled "Rookwood", and it was published in only three volumes.  But the Google books snippet claims it comes from volume 20.  I can't find "long odds" in any of the three volumes.  Here's Vol. 1: https://archive.org/details/06536987.5702.emory.edu

Comment: So, I think that entire Google books snippet is bogus.

Comment: At any rate, I'm not convinced "long odds" derives from "long shot", mainly because of the prominence of the term "long price" in horse betting.  See: https://books.google.com/books?id=bc0GDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT127&dq=horse+%22long+price%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik1pW4g63NAhUXR1IKHcQXB8IQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=horse%20%22long%20price%22&f=false

Comment: There's a mention there of bookmakers "lengthening" the price on a horse, which would indicate to me that the usage of "long" is in literal reference to the magnitude of the price rather than some figurative adaptation of "long shot" meaning "high odds against".

Comment: @Dr. Funk: You can find *Rookwood* on [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/23564) and check that it does indeed contain that quote. Book III, Chapter 9.

Comment: "Odds" has a great history of use in discussing inequalities, going back to the early 16th century (OED). Adjectives such as long, short, and even come into play around the times Peter relates, in gambling and other contexts.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41703/discussion-on-answer-by-peter-shor-where-does-the-expression-long-odds-come-f).

Answer (score -1):

It likely comes from the size of the payout relative to the size of the bet.

If a particular horse has a very small chance of winning, a bookmaker might "stand the horse at a long price", meaning the odds against are high, so the winnings will be much greater than the outlay.  Conversely, if the horse is the favorite to win, then you might stand to win less than your wager.

A bookmaker will set a "long price", an "even price", or a "short price" for a horse, depending on the odds.  An old, poor performer with 20-1 odds against is said to have a long price.  A horse with 1-1 odds is said to be priced at evens.  An overwhelming favorite - say, 2-3 against - is said to have a short price.

Paradoxically, however, a "short horse" in the American vernacular is actually a horse that performs poorly.  So, a "short horse" is actually the opposite of a "short priced horse".